# SQL Query to Retrieve data by comparing column name to a particular string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `SQL` Table consisting of customer, transaction and store. Store has 3 values (X,Y,Z)

I want to retrieve customers who shopped at particular store, so I used this query

```
select distinct customer from TABLE group by store.
```

However, now I want the customer details who shopped at 2 stores  (X,Y) (Y,Z) (Z,X) and also (X,Y,Z).

When I use

```
select distinct customer from TABLE where store='X'
```

it gives 0 results in `oracle SQL Developer`

How to proceed from here?

Comment: It says missing identifier

Comment: This is the actual code im using in SQL developer. I copy pasted it

Comment: I wonder how you save store**s** in the table, in one column? If so, what the actual value looks like when it has more than one store. And in this case you might want to use **where store like '%X%'**

Comment: ok store the string in a `varchar` and check it with `store=varcharVariable`

Comment: @spiritwalker

This is the sample data

STORE     CUSTOMER          TRANSACTION
X           4567              66666
X           4567              55555
X           2233              43216
Y           2345              67890
Y           4567              23456`

Comment: @ACB
No luck, it says missing left parenthesis. When I add corresponding parenthesis, it says missing identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
   Select Customer From
    (
         Select Customer,Store from TableName group by Store,Customer
    )tbl
    Group By Customer Having COUNT(Customer)>=2 Order By Customer
```

**Edit:**

```
Declare @MainTable table
(
  Customer varchar(222),Store varchar(2222)
)
Insert Into @MainTable
Select 'C1','X'
Union All
Select 'C1','Y'
Union All
Select 'C1','X'
Union All
Select 'C2','X'
Union All
Select 'C2','Y'
Union All
Select 'C2','Z'
Union All
Select 'C3','X'
Union All
Select 'C3','Z'
Union All
Select 'C4','X'
Union All
Select 'C4','Y'


Declare @temp table 
(
  Customer varchar(200)
)
Insert Into @temp 
Select Customer From
    (
         Select Customer,Store from @MainTable group by Store,Customer
    )tbl
Group By Customer Having COUNT(Customer)>=2 Order By Customer


Declare @Customer_Store table 
(
  Customer varchar(200),
  Stores varchar(200)
)

DECLARE @Stores varchar(10)
Declare @Customer varchar(256)
While((Select COUNT(*) From @temp)>0)
Begin
        Set @Customer=(Select Top 1 Customer From @temp)
        Select @Stores=coalesce(@Stores + ',','') + Store From 
        @MainTable Where Customer=@Customer
        Group By Store
        Order By Store

        Insert Into @Customer_Store Select @Customer,@Stores

        Delete From @temp Where Customer=@Customer
        Set @Stores=null
End


Select Cast(COUNT(Customer) as Varchar(5))+' Customers shopped at Store ('+Stores+')'          CustomerDetail From @Customer_Store
Group By Stores
```

Output:

```
2 Customers shopped at Store (X,Y)
1 Customers shopped at Store (X,Y,Z)
1 Customers shopped at Store (X,Z)
```

Comment: Thanks, i think it worked. I got customers who shopped at 2 or more stores. 

But I want to know the values separately like, n no of customers shopped at (X,Y) m at (Y,Z) and p at all three. Is there any way?

Comment: I have edited answer above and have included sample code to your problem. Check if this works for you.

Comment: You're grouping by the customer and counting them?

Comment: query will return the number of customers shopped at different stores and has shopped at more than one store.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct customer from tablename group by customer ,store  having count(stores)>2

sorry....you can try like this

"select customer,store from table_name group by customer ,store having count(customer)>=1 order by customer asc"

i hope this is correct.

Comment: Nope, its giving all the rows including those who shop at single store

Comment: now i have edited the query just try it out like this,.
 

select customer,store from table_name group by customer ,store having count(customer)>=1 order by customer asc

Comment: Its still returning all the rows.

Comment: i am working on sqlserver 2008....just check this..select customer,trans,store from table_name group by customer ,trans,store having count(customer)>=1 order by customer asc

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in MySQL.

[Here you can find how you can emulate it in Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)

For example for Oracle 11g R2 you can use LISTAGG:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35085/6)

```
SELECT customer, 
       LISTAGG(store, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY store) 
       AS STORES
FROM   
(select distinct customer,store from t) t1
GROUP BY customer;
```